# DataGrip SQL Code Style - List Items Wrapping not Chopping

Tags: pycharm, datagrip

I've been messing around with the Code Style options in PyCharm (but for SQL, hence the DataGrip title):

[image: Code Style Option]

Although I can get almost everything to the style that I use, I can't figure out how to get lists to format how I expect

**I'm hoping that answers to this question will show me which settings to change to get the behaviour that I want (explained below)**

There's 2 behaviours that I want to enforce:

1. The items in a list should always Chop
2. The items in a list should be on a new line, indented once from the start of the opening line (not relative to the opening parenthesis, though)

I've changed all of my wrapping options to Chop (or Chop If Long) across all of the settings and I've changed most of the alignment options to Wrapped Unindented (where I think it'll make a difference), but lists are still only wrapping if they're long and the alignment is not working as expected -- I can't figure out which options apply to lists

#### Current Behaviour (Not Wanted)

##### Short List

Consider the following query with a short list:

```
SELECT
    table_name,
    column_name,
    data_type
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE 1=1
    AND table_schema = 'Schema'
    AND data_type NOT IN ('item', 'item')
ORDER BY
    table_name,
    ordinal_position
;
```

The 'Format Code' action (Ctrl + Alt + L) does nothing notable to this query

However, when I place the cursor before the first `'item'` and click the enter key, it places the text on the next line but aligned with the opening parenthesis:

```
...
    AND data_type NOT IN (
                          'item', 'item')
...
```

Clicking the enter key with the cursor before the second `'item'` and then the closing parenthesis leaves the code formatted like:

```
...
    AND data_type NOT IN (
                          'item',
                          'item'
                         )
...
```

###### Long List

Consider the following query with a long list:

```
SELECT
    table_name,
    column_name,
    data_type
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE 1=1
    AND table_schema = 'Schema'
    AND data_type NOT IN ('item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item')
ORDER BY
    table_name,
    ordinal_position
;
```

Clicking the enter key with the cursor before the items behaves in the same way as described above

However, the 'Format Code' action (Ctrl + Alt + L) wraps these items and aligns with the opened parenthesis:

```
SELECT
    table_name,
    column_name,
    data_type
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE 1=1
    AND table_schema = 'Schema'
    AND data_type NOT IN
        ('item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item',
         'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item', 'item')
ORDER BY
    table_name,
    ordinal_position
;
```

#### Intended Behaviour

Regardless of the formatting method (enter key or Format Code action), the list behaviour that I want is:

```
SELECT
    table_name,
    column_name,
    data_type
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE 1=1
    AND table_schema = 'Schema'
    AND data_type NOT IN (
        'item',
        'item'
    )
ORDER BY
    table_name,
    ordinal_position
;
```

Here, the list items are all on a new line, indented from the opening line, and not aligned with the opening parenthesis

#### Software Details

- PyCharm Pro version 2022.1 (Build #PY-221.5080.212)
- DataGrip plugin: Database Tools and SQL (bundled 221.5080.212)
- Microsoft SQL Azure version 12.0.2000.8 (very similar to Microsoft SQL Server)

#### Current Settings

My current settings are included below -- all changes have been made to the 'General' settings with all dialects inheriting these settings

###### Case

[image: Case Options]

###### Queries

[image: Queries Options]

###### DDL

[image: DDL Options]

###### Code

[image: Code Options]

###### Expressions

[image: Expressions Options]

###### Tabs and Indents

[image: Tabs and Indents Options]

###### Wrapping

[image: Wrapping Options]

###### Code Generation

[image: Code Generation Options]

Comment: Could you specify SQL dialect you work with?

Comment: @VasiliiChernov Yeah it's the SQL Server dialect :) I'll note that I've just configured the General settings and have all dialects inheriting from that one

Comment: Also, I noticed [an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/DBE-15550/Allow-List-Item-Chopping-in-Code-Style) you've created. Thank you for that!

Comment: This question has also been asked on the JetBrains Community forum: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/5507622514322-DataGrip-SQL-Code-Style-List-Items-Wrapping-not-Chopping